# Can't run crond in docker container permission denied

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile i use to build a fairly complex image, i want to be able to use crontab inside the container. I won't post the entire dockerfile, but this is the basics to outline the issue:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt update

RUN apt-get install -y cron

RUN echo "* * * * * php /usr/share/nginx/html/bin/console processvideo" >> /etc/crontab

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

The crontab gets written no problem but my container crashes and logs:

```
cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied
```

Not sure how to solve it so it can run?

Comment: I don't see a permission error when running an image built from this Dockerfile. Are you mounting any volumes on your `docker run` command line? Or does your actual Dockerfile include any `USER` directives?

Comment: It’s inside a php fpm container the only user commands I have are setting the id of the www-data user to one I want. The rest of the docker file is just installing php libraries

Comment: Sorry yes I’m mounting a volume for the log file and there are others for the application uploads etc but nothing that should cause this permission error

Answer (score 1):

If I build an image `crontest` using your example `Dockerfile`, I don't see the behavior you have described. I see this error:

```
tail: cannot open '/var/log/cron.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

But that's expected; `/var/log/cron.log` doesn't exist because `cron` logs to `syslog`, so you would need to arrange to run a syslog daemon. This would work:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt update

RUN apt-get install -y cron busybox

RUN echo "* * * * * php /usr/share/nginx/html/bin/console processvideo" >> /etc/crontab

CMD cron && busybox syslogd -n -O-
```

Here I'm using the `busybox` implementation of `syslogd`, which can be configured to run in the foreground and log to stdout.  If I use this slightly modified `Dockerfile` (it contains a different command in the `crontab` entry):

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt update

RUN apt-get install -y cron busybox

RUN echo "* * * * * root date >> /tmp/crontest.txt 2>&1" >> /etc/crontab

CMD cron && busybox syslogd -n -O-
```

Then I see in the container console output:

```
$ docker run  --rm crontest
May 31 16:58:59 7efb36661954 syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.30.1
May 31 16:59:01 7efb36661954 authpriv.err CRON[5]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
May 31 16:59:01 7efb36661954 authpriv.info CRON[5]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 31 16:59:01 7efb36661954 cron.info CRON[6]: (root) CMD (date >> /tmp/crontest.txt 2>&1)
May 31 16:59:01 7efb36661954 authpriv.info CRON[5]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 31 17:00:01 7efb36661954 authpriv.err CRON[8]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
May 31 17:00:01 7efb36661954 authpriv.info CRON[8]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
May 31 17:00:01 7efb36661954 cron.info CRON[9]: (root) CMD (date >> /tmp/crontest.txt 2>&1)
May 31 17:00:01 7efb36661954 authpriv.info CRON[8]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

---

(Incidentally, in your example, you have a crontab entry for user `php` but there is not `php` user in `/etc/passwd`.)

---

This also works for me when deploying to a Docker Swarm instance using:

```
version: "3"

services:
  cron:
    image: crontest
```

Comment: No I’m trying to run a php command line program , maybe this is why then I’m missing the user

Comment: Ok so i've been playing around and if i run this in a container it's fine, it's when i run it on a docker swarm stack it has the issue, the log of the service in the stack shows: cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior: the example here runs correctly when I `docker stack deploy` it to a local swarm. Can you update your question to include a `docker-compose.yaml` (or equivalent) file that results in this behavior in your environment?